# Application of Stokes' Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the integral  $\int_\Gamma(z-y)dx+(x-z)dy+(y-x)dz$ by using Stokes' Theorem. Where $\Gamma$ is surface obtained from intersection $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x+2z=1$.

I don't know how to solve this problem. I'm sitting with it 5 hours. Help me please.  I've read about Stokes' Theorem, but I don't know how to apply. Indications are not helping. Could you please write the solution. Please refrain from general indications such as read that and try that. If you can please provide a complete solution. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: what is the region??

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam please see updated version

Comment: If $\Gamma$ is given by the intersection of a cylinder and a plane, it would seem to be a curve rather than a surface.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem lies in parametrising the above surface. Now observe $x$ and $y$ must lie on the circle .

so let $$x=rcos\theta,y=rsin\theta,z=\frac{1-rcos\theta}{2}$$ where $0\le\theta\le2\pi$, $0\le r\le1$

Now I guess by stokes's theorem $$\int_{\tau}F.ds=\int\int_{s}(curlF).ds$$.

You can use $$\phi(r,\theta)=(rcos\theta,rsin\theta,\frac{1-rcos\theta}{2})$$
$$\int\int_{s}(curlF).ds=\int\int_DcurlF(\phi(r,\theta)).(\phi_{r}\times\phi_{\theta})drd\theta$$

Here $$F=(z-y,x-z,y-x)$$

Comment: Thanks very much, is that complete?

Comment: you need to carry out the calculation yourslf